# Spring MVC - Correct way for session validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Currently in most of my controller classes i check whether the session exists for each mapping.

For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController{

@GetMapping
public ModelAndView admin(HttpSession session){
if(exists(session)){
...
}
}

@GetMapping("/addUser")
public ModelAndView user(HttpSession session){
if(exists(session)){
...
}
}

@GetMapping("/addBook")
public ModelAndView book(HttpSession session){
if(exists(session)){
...
}
}
```

Is there a way i can check session once the AdminController is called, instead of checking session for each mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First of all, in case you can, switch to `Spring Boot`. Configuration will be easier then.*

Yes, in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterImpl` you can specify, that the user must have a certain role to access certain areas. In your case it would be

```
http
    .antMatches("/admin/**").hasRole(<UserRole.Admin>);
```

You can also use `PreAuthorize`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController{
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView admin(HttpSession session){

    }
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/addUser")
    public ModelAndView user(HttpSession session){

    }
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/addBook")
    public ModelAndView book(HttpSession session){

    }

}
```

You have to enable using this annotation. It's described in the [Documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

So summarizing, you need `Spring Security`, then either configure access in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or enable annotation based access control and then specify the `@PreAuthorize`.

**Edit:**
OK, as the OP has asked for clarification, I decided to add some more general information about using `Spring Security`.

In `Spring Security` we base on `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` which returns `UserDetails` on login. Although, I recommend you to refactor your code and just have one class `User` which has a `Collection` of `authorities` you can do the following.

Create new class which would be `UserDetailsImpl` which would implement `UserDetails`. Also create some custom roles like `ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_ADMIN`. They should be an enum. Then in your `UserDetailsImpl` have fields that are important during the session - logged user UUID, name, email and some somehow required by the interface - `isAccountLocked`, `isPasswordExpired` etc, Also you'll need a collection of authorities which you'll return by a certain method.

You'll be able to use `hasRole` in your code then. What is cool, you'll also be able to get the logged user details in your application from the context.

Comment: I dont have an instance variable/enum as Role. Login object has user id. Upon login i check if the user object(fetched from db) is an instance of class Admin and then i route it accordingly. Can I do something similar with this approach?

Comment: @ShashankRaghunath ok, the topic is pretty wide, but I'll describe it for you in the answer in a minute

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to involve Spring Security, you can add an interceptor that will intercept all requests.

```
public class SessionCheck extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
   public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
      return exists(request.getSession());
   }
}
```